# In a JavaScript engine like V8, does an object consume more memory than a function that returns it?

Tags: javascript, memory, v8, string-literals, object-literal

Let's say I have a non-trivial static data structure:

```
[
  { id: 1, title: 'Long title 1...' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Long title 2...' },
  /* 998 more... */
]
```

Considering my app will infrequently need to map/filter this (and I assume keep the module in memory), would it consume less memory to (A) export it as a const:

```
export const rows = [ ... ];
```

Or (B), export a function that returns the literal:

```
export function getRows() {
  return [ ... ];
}
```

Or (C), export a function that JSON.parses a string literal?

```
export function getRows() {
  return JSON.parse("[ ... ]");
}
```

To be clear the concern is its contribution to RAM consumption of a browser tab for the length of the page lifetime. A transient spike in RAM usage during infrequent operations is less of a concern.

I know in (B) and (C), each invocation may incur some object construction time, but that's not as concerning as taking up RAM. I know (C) defers the parsing time of the literal, but it's not clear if the parsed representation consumes more RAM than its JSON string literal.

Comment: Using `JSON.parse()` (the third option) would be really silly. Between the first two, there's basically no difference, though why you wouldn't want the simplicity of the first one is a mystery.

Comment: The function contains the object that it's going to return. So it has to use more memory than the object literal by itself.

Comment: What does your [profiling debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/diagnostics/memory/using-heap-profiler) tell you?

Comment: Also if your data set is truly enormous, then it should probably be in a database. JavaScript object representation means that your property names are redundantly stored in every object. A good runtime might optimize that a little, but in a database you'd have a schema and much more efficient storage.

Comment: @Barmar Definitely the function contains the object *while it's running*, but does it after?

Comment: @Pointy The canonical source is a DB but the data changes almost never so it makes sense to burn it into the deployed source *somewhere*.

Comment: If it doesn't contain it, how can it return it? It might not contain the object itself, but it contains code that constructs the object, which has to include at least as much memory as the object.

Comment: It's likely to be code equivalent to `return Object.structuredClone({...})`.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure that the source code tree consumes as much memory as the constructed object variable? I wouldn't assume that without an understanding of the interpreter source.

Comment: @SteveClay I'm not talking about source code, I'm talking about the result of compiling the source code.

Comment: @Pointy: one benefit of shared "hidden classes" is that property names are _not_ stored in every object. The object has a pointer to its hidden class, the hidden class has the names of the properties, the object only stores the properties' values.

Comment: @jmrk that sounds interesting but I am not familiar with hidden classes *edit* oh I see, it's a V8 optimization, makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Short answer may be “yes”. From the testing I performed [in this repo](https://github.com/mrclay/node-mem-test), **the "winner" was (C)** with the least long-term memory consumption, with (B) consuming twice the memory, and (A) *4x* the memory.

Surely this will depend on the size and shape of the data. In this case:

| Case | Module export | Size on disk (b) | Bytes added to "heapUsed" after 30s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | Function using JSON.parse() | 1,400,667 | 1,934,336 |
| B | Function returning literal | 1,379,845 | 4,422,656 |
| A | Const | 1,379,828 | 9,018,368 |

Each module was tested separately, first capturing the output of `memoryUsage()`, then loading the data module dynamically, accessing the data, then waiting 10s and 30s after loading and re-measuring memory usage then (not allowing the imported resource to fall out of scope). The results from 3 runs can be seen [in this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QMMTd_77MloJSTDsCPOFXbYEKQ7MXySbBMKWA69kuY0/edit?usp=sharing) (the values are deltas in kB from the baseline call to `memoryUsage()`).

What I suspect is going on is that a single large JSON string in source code can be stored in contiguous RAM whereas the other two representations require a lot more individual objects and expensive "edges" for lack of a better term. And it's pretty surprising that the constructed variable takes up *twice* the memory as the compiled representation of a function returning the object as a literal!

But maybe it shouldn’t be surprising: I assume the AST of a literal can’t be GC-ed regardless of if it’s a const or function so while the module is in scope you’re always paying that memory cost on top of any variable storage. *All things equal*, try to store as little on the heap for as short as possible.

Comment: Now that there’s a repo, I should try a much smaller object as well as an array of similar objects as in the question.

Comment: It makes sense that for certain object graphs (in particular, many small objects pointing at each other) the JSON representation is smaller than the in-memory size of the objects themselves. This won't be true for all object graphs though, it depends on your specific data. What I find surprising in your results is that B takes less memory than C, that _might_ be a measuring artifact. You could try explicitly triggering a GC cycle (using `node --expose-gc` and `gc();`) instead of waiting 20 seconds.